# How to draw custom shapes inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, quartz-2d

Hi i am trying to create my own time line view using UISCrollView

1. I want to create Year view (need to draw using quartz library) which size is 1200, 50.

Sample code is:

```
- (void)drawYearScaleMain
{
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.contentSize.width, self.bounds.origin.y);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.contentSize.width, 50);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, 50);
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y);
     CGContextFillPath(context);
 }
```

1. Same now i want to create Month view using same type of drawing code:

Sample code:

```
- (void)drawMonthScaleSub
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.6, 0.2, 0.8);

    CGFloat topLeftX = self.bounds.origin.x;
    CGFloat topLeftY = 50;
    CGFloat width = 98;
    CGFloat height = 30;

    for(int count = 0; count<12; count++)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(topLeftX, topLeftY, width, height);
        CGContextFillRect(context, frame);
        topLeftX = topLeftX + 10 + width;
    }

}
```

but if i scroll my scrollview what ever i drawn in this view is not scrolling, if there is any mistake in my code, or any other best way to achieve this.

kindly suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you u missed all things to adding in scrollview.. and give proper content size to scrollview

Comment: Try to use UIView subclass and use it's `drawRect:` method to draw then but it as a subview in your scrollview.

Comment: i called this methods inside the drawRect: method of UIScrollView subclass. still while scrolling the view, the custom drawn are not scrolling along with the view. And my scroll view contentSize is (1200, 1200)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a subclass of UIView and reimplement `DrawRect:` method. Then you should put this view in your scrollView.